# Nested JSON request - PostMapping in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I need to create a post request in Springboot and call an API to update records. The mapping JSON layout is a nested one as mentioned below :

```
{
  "Config": {
    "Identity": "",
    "Region": ""
  },
  "OPTION_IP_COLL": {
    "OPTION_NAME": "",
    "OPTION_VALUE": ""
  },
  "REC_XPFH": {
    "UPDATE_CD": "",
    "ENTITY_TYPE": "",
    "TN_ID": "",
    "PR_ID": ""
  },
  "REC_GRP": {
    "REC_PRPR": {
      "PR_UPDATE_CD": "",
      "PR_ENTITY": "",
      "PR_CL_EFT_IND": "",
      "PR_EDI_DEST_ID": "",
      "PR_RA_DEST_IND": ""
    },
    "REC_MCBR": {
      "BD_ID": "",
      "BR_ACCT_NO": "",
      "BR_ACCT_NAME": "",
      "BR_ACCT_NO_QUA": ""
    }
  }
}
```

As this is a nested one, I am bit confused how to define a POJO(it should be single or multiple) for this request and call it in @PostMapping. I am thinking to create one Main POJO and then different classes for other segments and then call the Main one in the RestController class. I am not sure whether this is a right way to do it or is there something else that I could try. Also, I need some assistance to define REC_GRP class as there are nested segments involved.

**MainPOJO.class**

```
public class ProviderMappingPOJO {
    
    private Config config;
    private OPTIONAL_IP_CALL option_ip_call;
    private REC_XPFH rec_xpfh ;
    private REC_GRP rec_grp;

//getter and setter method .....
```

**Config.class**

```
private String Identity ;
private String Region;
// getters and setters method...
```

**OPTION_IP_COLL.class**

```
private String UPDATE_CD;
private String ENTITY_TYPE;
private String TN_ID;
private String PR_ID;

// getter and setter methods ...
```

**REC_XPFH.class**

```
 // Not sure how to define structure for this as there are nested segments
```

**RestController.class**

```
 public class RestController {
    
 @PostMapping(url)
 public <> getProviderDetails(@RequestBody MainPOJO main){
     
    // code 

}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "multiple segments  involved"?

Comment: @Praveenks you can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ link to generate POJOs based on the JSON data with Source type=Json config from the same link...

Comment: @sagar.tarle Thanks !! This was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one main pojo and inside that main pojo, you can define child pojos as you are mentioned above.

```
    public class MainPOJO {    
        private Config config;
        private OPTIONAL_IP_CALL option_ip_call;
        private REC_XPFH rec_xpfh ;
        private REC_GRP rec_grp;

        // setters and getters
    }
```

You can refer the below links, which will helps you to get a clear understanding about the conversion process.

https://dzone.com/articles/converting-json-to-pojos-using-java

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

https://www.freecodeformat.com/json2pojo.php

Once you completed the conversion, you can use the Spring Rest controller to consume the json.

```
    public class RestController {

        @PostMapping(path="url", consumes = "application/json")
        public <> getProviderDetails(@RequestBody MainPOJO main){
 
           // code 
        }
    }
```